# Email address is missing on Thank You page where it says "An email confirmation with these payment instructions has been sent to"

Tags: contribution-page

Noticed this on a couple of sites - not sure if this is a bug yet. When I tested on dmaster it fills correctly so perhaps this is a bug/regression that has been fixed between 4.7.27 and 4.7.30/31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CiviCRM Core bug, reported here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/173

It applies to pay later contributions when the email address is included in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

I see this too. I believe its only when the pay later is enabled and the donor selects pay later. The email addresss is not shown. A simple hack may be to find the code change it to just "has been sent." until someone with more knowledge than me can fix the problem. I tried it with a 4.6.X version (on Joomla) and the email showed properly. I tried it with a 4.7.X (on Wordpress, I forget which version I was at! 32?) and had the problem. So I upgraded that to 5.0.2 and still have the problem.

Comment: Thansk for commenting. My testing on Sandbox is that it shows the email address for Pay Later too. "An email confirmation with these payment instructions has been sent to demo@example.com." So am going to ignore and assume it has been fixed as a bug already.

Comment: one of us may have to test on the  5.1 release tomorrow

Comment: I can confirm this problem with CiviCRM 4.7.27 + Drupal 7. Upgrading to CiviCRM 5.2 does not resolve the issue, so I believe this is still a bug. It would seem there are additional conditions for the problem - I suspect it might be only showing up when an email is included in the profile.

Comment: And I can also confirm it doesn't show up when I disable the email in the profile.